Showing $\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab+(k-3)bc+ca}{(b-c)^2+kbc}\ge\frac{3(k-1)}{k}$ for positive reals $a, b, c, k$
A hard inequality by Vascile Cartoaje:

Let $a, b, c, k$ be positive reals. Prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab+(k-3)bc+ca}{(b-c)^2+kbc}\ge\frac{3(k-1)}{k}$$

I came across this inequality in a handout by Thomas Mildorf. I wasn't able to prove it myself and couldn't find a proof that doesn't use $uvw$. Can this inequality be proven by elementary means (AM-GM, Cauchy, Schur, ...) or at least with basic analysis?

The inequality in question is equivalent to $k\sum a^5 b + (k^2-5k+3)\sum a^4 b^2 + (k - 3)\sum a^4 b c + (-k^2+4k-3)\sum a^3 b^3 + (-2k+6)\sum a^3 b^2 c + (6k - 18) a^2 b^2 c^2 \ge 0$, where $\sum$ denotes a symmetric sum.

A proof by Vascile himself:
The inequality is equivalent to
$$k\sum_{sym} a^5 b + (k^2-5k+3)\sum_{sym} a^4 b^2 + (k - 3)\sum_{sym} a^4 b c + (-k^2+4k-3)\sum_{sym} a^3 b^3 + (-2k+6)\sum_{sym} a^3 b^2 c + (6k - 18) a^2 b^2 c^2 \ge 0
$$
For $k\ge3$, this is equivalent to
$$k\sum_{cyc} bc(b^2+bc+c^2)(b-c)^2 + (k-1)(k-3)\sum_{cyc} b^2 c^2 (b-c)^2 + 2(k-3)abc\sum_{cyc} a(a-b)(a-c)\ge0$$
Here we used Schur's inequality in the last summand.
For $k<3$, this is equivalent to
$$(3-k)(b-c)^2(c-a)^2(a-b)^2+k\sum_{cyc} bc(b-c)^4 + k^2\sum_{cyc} b^2c^2(b-c)^2\ge0$$
Hence we are done :)
